# Magento Customers Cannot Login

Tags: session, magento, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I recently moved my Magento store to a new server and now customers are unable to login to their accounts.

On the login page, when you enter the correct email and password, the page simply refreshes, with no message or anything. If you enter the wrong password, it will give you a message telling you so. This leads me to believe that it's a cookie/session issue (maybe the cookie is expiring immediately?) The problem is I have no idea how to go about fixing it...

I have already cleared the var/cache and var/session folders, as well as my browser cache, with no success. Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm running Magento 6.2 on MageMojo.com hosting

Comment: This always happens to me if I go to the project root and enter `chown -R myuser:www *`. Then I can't login anymore. So it must have to do with file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

If the URL or domain of the site has changed in the migration, check the "Cookie Domain" setting in System Config.  You find it under `General > Web > Session Cookie Management` and it's called "Cookie Domain".

If this parameter doesn't match your site's actual domain name, what happens is that the login form is submitted, the user is logged in and a session cookie issues.  The user's browser is then redirected to the protected page, but the cookie is not sent with the new request, so Magento believes the user has not yet logged in.

The main symnptom to look for if it's a cookie domain issue is as follows. The user submits the login form and when the form is displayed again there's no message indicating the user failed to log in.  However, if they enter an incorrect username or password the message does appear.

Generally cookie domain can be left blank and the site works as expected.

Comment: This worked for me - after making the change in the Admin, my iPhone was still redirecting back to the login page, but after entering a wrong password (to delete the cookie), and then logging in again, everything worked as expected.

Comment: I have exactly these symptoms except I am actually logged in, it just doesn't appear so on the one page checkout page. I can tell because I am able to click on my account and my account is there. I have cookie path as /, cookie domain left blank, use http only and cookie restriction mode as no.
Any idea how I should fix in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a while since I've used Magento so don't remember exactly what kind of errors it returns when things aren't working. One thing to check could be that the relevant cache & session folders are writeable by the webserver and that the config has the correct paths to these if they have changed. Maybe see if anything gets written here when you try to login.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was Cookie Management set to 'Yes' try giving that a bash. Saved a lot of agro - this was for 1.9 Magento which already has all the login.phtml sorted - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35439/admin-login-problems-what-are-the-correct-settings-of-session-cookie-management/60187#60187